# coordinates on google map

Tags: google-maps, dictionary

i have list of coordinates that i taken from regular gps that we use in car.  This coordinates when i put in google maps code with javascript  don't work. What am i doing wrong here. Do i need to do any conversion !!!

```
var mapProp = {
      center:new google.maps.LatLng(N42°44.8437', W074°10.751'),
        zoom:16,
      mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
            var map=new    google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
    });
```

Comment: The Google Maps Javascript API uses decimal degrees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the LatLng function expects both arguments to be a number:

```
new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
```

So yes, you do need to do a conversion first. Check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#LatLng):

- Latitude ranges between -90 and 90 degrees, inclusive. Values above
  or below this range will be clamped to the nearest value within this
  range. For example, specifying a latitude of 100 will set the value
  to 90.
- Longitude ranges between -180 and 180 degrees, inclusive. Values above or below this range will be wrapped such that they fall within
  the range [-180, 180). For example, 480, 840 and 1200 will all be
  wrapped to 120 degrees.

and see this [sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=nl)